# Battlefield applications for illusory powers?

Tags: illusion

Someone is capable of bending light to create illusions with conscious thought. They must concentrate to create an illusion, and larger illusions (larger than a human) are incredibly taxing on the mind and body, causing the illusionist to feel physically and mentally exhausted. They can, for example, create several illusory soldiers or make a small group of soldiers disappear, but this would take a lot of effort.

Other than hiding troops/creating fake troops to make a distraction, what could an illusionist in an army do in order to increase the chances of victory against an enemy army?

Comment: Imagination is the limit. This is an open ended brainstorming question. You should read up on what are good and bad questions for this site.

Comment: basically _everything_ you could imagine is either hiding your troops or distracting the enemy.

Comment: What if the light is bended to make the enemy see the troops at a different location? Just like when you try to spear a fish underwater, the fish isnt where you see it. Water refraction occurs when the light travels from one medium (air) to another (water). Perhaps its just to make the enemy waste ammunition, or to surprise it with a running charge that suddenly is coming a little more towards the flanks instead of head on.

Comment: [Dazzle camouflage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dazzle_camouflage) - instead of attempting to *hide* something, it's about using more prominent markings to confuse the enemy. For example, a ship might be painted in order to look like it's backwards, or that it's moving at an angle it's not. Therefore when catching a glimpse of it and trying to plot its course to hit it with a torpedo, the course would be off, thus the attack would fail. Even though the ship itself is no less visible. These are rather light illusions that should not be very taxing.

Comment: @Gault Drakkor It isn't open-ended with infinite possibilities, such high cost, non-material power limit this to mostly subterfuges. Besides, battlefields (and military needs in general) need the most efficient-to-cost way of dealing with things, further stated by the high cost of illusions. Therefore answers can be ranked and the question is not opinion-based :). Can be improved however, which I'm going to detail below.

Comment: @Truthseeker the dragon I think you could get more accurate answers if you gave more details  Can you give an era and place kind your illusionist live in : 20th century, early antiquity, late medieval European Age, space pewpew future...? Is there only one illusionist or many? Also, if you happen to know more about how your illusions work, it'll help :). Answering about magic applications can be easier if you give more data about its inner mechanisms.

Comment: Could you specify the properties of the illusions: For how long they can be maintained, and what is their range? Also, do the illusions conform to the laws of our universe?

Answer (score 4):

## Blind People

Your illusionist redirects light.  Rather than spreading that out over the space required to make a projection of soldiers, direct all the light from a given area into as many enemy eyeballs as he can at a time.  The amount of control required to do so is substantially lower than producing a convincing image of something else.

As long as the illusionist is manipulating light, the battlefield application is that of a weapon, not misdirection.

Comment: And it is at this time people invented sunglasses :p.

Comment: @Tortliena Depending on how much light is around, the lightbender could go around sunglasses, overwhelm them... or melt them along with the wearer's head.  It's rather like [making puppies appear anywhere](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2006-06-08) - using the ability to manipulate light just to make illusory images is being uncreative when light has [more direct applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cooker).

Comment: Clever counter-application; just to add in, the manga Mahouka koukou rettousei used light bending to blind opponents durin' a race, then the shadows to trick opponents on the next race who surprisingly were all wearing sunglasses ;).

Answer (score 2):

**Boost morale!**

[image: light show]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGOlGq1ftdw

Dude is not so much for the battling and war making.  His fist is paci.  But his illusions make phenomenal entertainment!  He sets up sweet shows for the soldiers on his side.    They are boosts to morale!  Everyone feels better, more esprit de corps, better soldiering.

Also it remains a sweet gig for him once the war is done.  Civilians like awesome light shows too.

Answer (score 1):

## Impersonate enemy leaders

It has been done before.

Last september my home country was at the brink of a civil war. A large group of truck drivers surrounded the supreme court and threatened physical violence against the justices within.

A local actor who is famous for his impressions of public figures recorded an audio message imitating the voice of the head of the insurgents. Then people spread the audio through social media. The message told the truck drivers to stay put and dance the Macarena as a display of support for their leader (I swear I am not making this up). A massive portion of the drivers fell for it and some even uploaded videos of themselves dancing. This made the leadership among the drivers lose command over the revolt and possibly avoided a coup.

Now that was a simple auditory illusion. Imagine what that actor could have done if he could have visually shapeshifted (even if just by illusion) into the the head of the revolutionists and walked among them. He could easily direct those guys into attacking another faction of their own side. He could break the enemy's chain of command and render enemy forces ineffective, all in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Very cool idea, far better that what I was thinking, but they would have to be careful if the leader has significantly different proportions. Because if the leader did, then the illusionist would have to be careful when moving items to make sure the items behave correctly.